# Customize 'react-datepicker' css

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

So I render this `'react-datepicker'` to a custom container, like so:

```
<DatePicker
    {...bindedFormField}
    labelId={field.name + index}
    customInput={<DatePickerCustomInput {...bindedFormField} />}
    popperContainer={CalendarContainer}
    dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
    locale="pl"
    selected={field.value}
    onChange={(value) => field.onChange(field.name, value)}
    minDate={field.dateConfig?.minDate}
    minTime={field.dateConfig?.minDate}
    maxDate={field.dateConfig?.maxDate}
    maxTime={field.dateConfig?.maxDate}
    showTimeSelect
/>
```

where the container is:

```
import { Portal } from 'react-overlays';

export const CalendarContainer = ({ children }) => {
    const el = document.getElementById('calendar-portal')
    return (
        <Portal container={el}>
            {children}
        </Portal>
    )
}
```

My question is this: how can I customie the css of the DatePicker (more specifically - I want to increase the `z-index`). I'll add that `document.getElementById('calendar-portal')` is null, it doesn't exist.

Comment: if you wanted to get it by id you would need to first give it one `<Portal id="calendar-portal">` but why not just give it a class and apply styles that way? `<Portal className="z-up">` `.z-up {z-index: 100000;}`. Also, the recommended way to access DOM nodes is by implementing `useRef`

Comment: @pilchard TypeScript error: Property 'className' does not exist on type...

Comment: Apparently TypeScript is missing proptypes for className, you just need to define them, though you might check the library repo and see if anyone else has issues.

Comment: Looks like in the docs they just wrap the `Overlay` in a div which they apply styles to. The div is assigned a `ref` and passed to the `Overlay` via the `container` prop.  `return ( <div className="flex flex-col items-center" ref={containerRef}>...<Overlay container={containerRef}`

Comment: I have the same issue now... If there is anyone can help, would be nice.